# Spring AMQP convertSendAndReceive with Restful multi threaded producer

Tags: java, spring, spring-amqp

I am trying to decide whether convertSendAndReceive is going to work for the following use case:

I have a RESTful web service that needs to make RPC calls and get a response back in order to service the request. I've never used the reply-to functionality in spring-amqp or RabbitMQ for that matter.

Will this work or am I headed down a path fraught with peril?

EDIT: My concern is whether the thread producing the message will get the correct corresponding response back and not get another thread's response.

I have added to a test that's listed in the spring-amqp documentation called [JavaConfigFixedReplyQueueTests](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/blob/master/spring-rabbit/src/test/java/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/listener/JavaConfigFixedReplyQueueTests.java). I added the following test case:

*(My connectionFactory bean is different but that's just to specify our SSL configuration for my company's rabbitmq instance so I'm not listing that here. All the existing tests passed with that change.)*

```
@Test
public void testReplyContainer_multiple_threads() throws Exception
{
    fixedReplyQRabbitTemplate.setReplyTimeout(-1);
    // limit the number of actual threads
    int poolSize = 100;
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(poolSize);
    List<Future<?>> futures = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int n = 0; n < 1000; n++)
    {
        Future<?> f = service.submit(makeNumberedRunnable(n));
        futures.add(f);
    }

    // wait for all tasks to complete before continuing
    for(Future<?> f : futures)
    {
        f.get();
    }

    // shut down the executor service so that this thread can exit
    service.shutdownNow();
}

private Runnable makeNumberedRunnable(int n)
{
    return new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            assertEquals("FOO" + n, fixedReplyQRabbitTemplate.convertSendAndReceive("foo" + n));
        }
    };
}
```

Basically my test is creating many threads and making sure that the correct thread specific response is returned. The test passes just fine which gives me a little confidence in my approach.

I'm hoping [Gary Russell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1240763/gary-russell) can chime in or maybe [Artem Bilan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2756547/artem-bilan) to give me their expert opinion. However, I welcome anyone knowledgeable in this area to give me their advice.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the `...sendAndReceive(...)` methods will properly correlate the request/reply so that the proper reply is returned on the requesting thread.

Comment: Thanks Gary! I thought that was the case but I couldn't find where anyone was doing a multithreading producer like mine so I wanted to be sure.

Comment: It's a pretty fundamental requirement - the framework would be pretty unusable if you couldn't rely on such things.

Comment: I'd rather ask this question and look like an idiot here than implement several mission critical solutions that break in production. :-)